# How to load all instances of entity / property?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4, properties, entity

i have some Data in a TableView (loaded from coreData) and now i want to upload this data to a webserver.

Before i can do that i want to save all data to a *.txt file.

How can i load all instances of an entity / property to an mutable array?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"barCode" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```

Thanks,
brush51

Edit 1:
Can you give me a little Help **(i dont want ALL data, just the property "barCode")**, now i have this code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[req setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[req setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError *error;
NSArray *codes = [moc executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
[req release];

    for (NSManagedObject *Event in codes) {
    NSLog(@"there it is : ------------> %@", codes);
    NSLog(@"barcodes ------------------> %@", [[managedObject valueForKey:@"barCode"] description]);
}
```

**How to output ONLY the instances of the property "barCode" ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a fetch request on the entity without a predicate, you'll get all the instances.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for answering,
here is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"barCode" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```

I have no predicate... Predicate is for what?